# How to return value after async function done

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having problem with async function, in this senario, i want to return true **outside async function** after it run successful, but i still stuck, here is example of that

```js
const returnSomethingIfHaveData = () => {
  const someAsyncFunc = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products/1').then(()=>true)
      return data
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } 
  };
  if(someAsyncFunc().then(data=>data)===true) return true
  else if(someAsyncFunc().then(data=>data)===false) return false
  
  
};
console.log(returnSomethingIfHaveData()) // ==> always return nothing
```

Why it always false, and how to make it right? I mean i**t return true after it finish** or i mean how to make it wait until api call done, mean how to make it return true always?

Comment: "*how to make it wait until api call done*" - this is impossible. Best you can do is return a promise, and have the caller wait for it: `console.log(await someAsyncFunc())` or `someAsyncFunc().then(console.log)`

Comment: Hi @Bergi, but we can't not return value of `someAsyncFunction` ? Can we use that to be a return value of `returnSomethingIfIHave`?

Comment: The return value of `someAsyncFunction` is a promise. You can return that promise, you cannot immediately return the value that the promise will fulfill with later.